# How to create a centered floating icon above/on a card in Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm new to Vuetify and I'm trying to figure out how to get a floating icon bubble at the top of a card using Vuetify components and props etc. I assumed that a `v-badge` would be the most suitable component to use, but I'm not sure. I'm trying to achieve something like this, but with an icon inside the blue circle:

[image]

I've been trying something like this inside the `v-card`:

```
<v-badge overlap icon="mdi-shield-account"></v-badge>
```

I've been playing with `offset-x` and `offset-y` props but I'm not sure if that's suitable to be fixing the offsets given that width of the card could change depending on screen size. I don't want to fall back to sticking custom classes and styling onto every Vuetify component unnecessarily. Is there a more 'Vuetiful' way of doing this?

My full card looks something like this:

```
<v-card outlined class="px-5 py-5">
  <v-badge overlap icon="mdi-shield-account"></v-badge>
  <v-form ref="form-personal">
    <v-text-field label="Firstname" prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field label="Lastname" prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker"></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a demo: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-ir84x?file=/src/layout.vue)

This is the important bit:

```
<v-row justify="center">
    <v-col cols="auto">
        <v-sheet
            class="rounded-circle"
            color="blue"
            :height="50"
            :width="50"
            style="margin-top: -60px"
        >
            <v-icon class="px-3 py-3">
                mdi-shield-account
            </v-icon>
        </v-sheet>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

I would advice to use a [v-sheet](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sheets), center that with `v-row justify="center"` and `v-col cols="auto"` and then move that sheet upwards with `margin-top: -55px`. This way you can easily change the width, height or color without additional css.

It's also "responsive", but you might have to test it out yourself to ensure that.

Comment: It's working well and responsive, thank you. Would something as small as that be overkill as a separate single file component?

Comment: My pleasure! My rule is, if I have to use it more than once then I will make a component out of it. It saves the hassle of trying to keep everything look the same.